# Add <tags></tags> field to StackExchange Tagset RSS feed entries

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, feed, tag-filters

I've created a tagset with a lot of tags, and want to translate RSS somewhere (for example, into IRC-channel). It would be nice to have question tag-list in each entry — it will help to format quesiotns to see quickly, if the question is of the subject you are interested to read/answer now.

Current possible use of RSS:

```
[12:34:56] <SEFEED> Bla blabla bla BLABLA blablabla.......
[12:35:56] <SEFEED> blabla bla BLA blablablabla blablabla.......
[12:36:56] <SEFEED> bla BLABLA bla BLABLABLA blablabla.......
[12:37:56] <SEFEED> Blabla blablabla BLA bla bla blabla.......
[12:38:56] <SEFEED> Bla blabla bla BLABLA blablabla.......
```

I want a possibility to make:

```
[12:34:56] <SEFEED> [RUBY] [REGEX] [UTF] — Bla blabla bla BLABLA blablabla.......
[12:35:56] <SEFEED> [UBUNTU] [VIM] — blabla bla BLA blablablabla blablabla.......
[12:36:56] <SEFEED> [STARCRAFT 2] — bla BLABLA bla BLABLABLA blablabla.......
[12:37:56] <SEFEED> [GOOGLE CHROME] [EXTENSION] — Blabla blablabla BLA bla bla blabla.......
[12:38:56] <SEFEED> [SOME ANOTHER TAG] — Bla blabla bla BLABLA blablabla.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done, but we do it the same way that SO et al do:

```
<category scheme="http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="game-design" />
<category scheme="http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="history" />
<category scheme="http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/feeds/tags" term="game-system" />
```

The "term" is the actual tag.